# Get near airport details of a location from google map api

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have used geocode api from google maps.
Gives the location details in result, which includes location boundary, country, and some location specific details (only names).

For example I'm looking for the details of the city "Dubai":

here is the link that returns details http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=dubai&sensor=false

But I need airports near to the city Dubai.

*Also note that i'm going to write the codes in php.*

Comment: I have searched google, nothing found. I also you have to note that, in my project I have only the place name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will return airports and their locations + viewports

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=airport%20Dubai&sensor=false

Take a look of `Address Component Types` at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. this is what I'm looking for. Also you have to mention, return type in your answer. That means a user can return data in XML also by changing `geocode/xml`. Again thank you, It helped so much.